# After Animate UI view Size inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

i wonder if u could help out to fix my issue here.
For example i have 2 `UIViews` inside the UIScrollView, let say the first `UIView` i've changed the size of its height and at the same time i change the y axis of the second `UIView` as well through this animation method. here's my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^{
        CGRect rect = informationView.frame;
        rect.size.height += 100.f;
        informationView.frame = rect;

        CGRect rectAddView = additionalView.frame;
        rectAddView.origin.y += 100.f;
        additionalView.frame = rectAddView;
}];
```

After those have been rendered (the height and Y axis). It works fine. And i changed the content size of that UIscrollview so it can be scroll it down. Here's the problem when i try to scroll down, surprisingly the height of the First `UIView` and Y axis of the second UIView are back like from the beginning. i don't how & why. So i just need wise explanation if there's somebody could help me here. Thank you

Comment: Could you be more precise in what you mean by "when I try to scroll down" and "are back"? E.g., are your views onscreen when their values revert? Do you see the jump happening? Is it when you touch down to scroll, when you start scrolling, or what?

Comment: Yes i mean the values are revert when i start scrolling.

Comment: Does the jump happen onscreen?

Comment: Maybe not jump.But when i did horizontal scroll the size of UIView exactly return to the initial point or just before i resize the height of the UIView.

Comment: I had same issue, i don't know reason but wrapping these views into another view will fix your problem.UIScrollView -> Container View -> View1, View2.